# elFinder: Set current upload directory

Tags: elfinder

My goal is to set current upload directory when [elFinder](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder) is initialized. For example, my "Upload files" link has desired working directory, which generated dynamically. How to pass the directory to elFinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, I want to get hash dynamically.

How about this.

```php
$encode_func = function ($path, $root) {
    $p = $path == $root ? '' : substr($path, strlen($root)+1)
    if ($p === '')  {
        $p = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $hash = $this->crypt($p);
    $hash = strtr(base64_encode($hash), '+/=', '-_.');
    $hash = rtrim($hash, '.'); 
    return $hash;
};
$id   = '[uniqueId]_'; You must set same id into root option
$root = realpath('../image/data/');
$path = realpath('../image/data/product');
$hash = $id.$encode($path, $root);
$url_hash = '#elf_'.$hash;
```

Answer (score 2):

elFinder 2.1 can open direct to any folder with URL hash.

ex.

- Demo/Images:
  http://hypweb.net/elFinder-nightly/demo/2.1/#elf_l1_SW1hZ2Vz
- Demo/Welcome:
  http://hypweb.net/elFinder-nightly/demo/2.1/#elf_l1_V2VsY29tZQ

Comment: Thanks. One more question - how to generate the hash? Can you provide an example? Say I have in connector.php  'path'          => '../image/data/' and 'URL'           => '../image/data/', and need to open ../image/data/product/

Comment: Please access your elFinder by the web browser and change cwd to 'product' then check location bar. Or do you want to get hash dynamically?

Comment: Yes, I want to get hash dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Something simple based on nao-pon and elfinder class.

Step 1:
//in php make hash from your file path, e.g. dirname("root/images/iphone/iphone-6S.jpg"). 
It's mostly just base64_encode

```
function elfinder_hash_path($path)
{
        if ($path == '')
            $path = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $hash = substr($path, strlen("root-name")+1);
        // hash is used as id in HTML that means it must contain vaild chars
        // make base64 html safe and append prefix in begining
        $hash = strtr(base64_encode($hash), '+/=', '-_.');
        // remove dots '.' at the end, before it was '=' in base64
        $hash = rtrim($hash, '.');
        // append volume id to make hash unique
        return "l1_". $hash;
}
```

"l1" is automatic volume id in elfinder for first local filesystem.
Otherwise you can set your volume ID in connector.php options "id" => "myid",

Step 2:
If you call elfinder window from JS, then after elfinder initialize, 
bind elfinder onload event to jump to directory you want to.
In this case, saved in JS variable hasher, gotten from php.

```
var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
    url : 'elfinder/php/connector.php',  // connector URL (REQUIRED)
    lang: 'sk',
    height: okno_vyska
}).elfinder('instance');

elf.bind('load', function(event) { elf.exec('open', hasher); });
```

Update:
elf.exec('open', hasher) doesn't work, if hashed sub-subdirectory was not opened yet in this js session, thus it's not in cache and elfinder does nothing.
Workaround: either use
`window.location.hash = hasher;`
or update last used directory in local storage before elf init

```
localStorage.setItem('elfinder-lastdirelfinder', hasher);
```